# How to use an argument for variables to execute a method for a map with a set included

Tags: java, collections, set, maps

I am trying to write a method with an argument for the key of the map and the value of the map; the value is a set.

My method header is:

```
addMapEntry(String aKey, Set<String> aCustomer)
```

I'm not sure if the header is correct, but if it is, how would I execute the method, because I have tried things like:

```
map.AddMapEntry("one", "Sony");
```

I am just getting errors like:

```
method addMapEntry in class CompanyCatalogue cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual argument java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.Set<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion
```

I think the issue is with the fact i need to use a variable as the value for the map, as i have got it working with no argument and also with an argument for the key. I can't seem to match the argument for the value into anything i can use in the method.

instance variable

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> systemsSold;
```

Constructor

```
public CompanyCatalogue()
   {
      systemsSold = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
   }
```

my Method

```
public void addMapEntry(String aUniqueKey, String aCustomer)
   {
      Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
      newSet.add("Joe");
      newSet.add("Mike");
      systemsSold.put(aUniqueKey, aCustomer);

   }
```

This has gone way over my head, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Your `addMapEntry` requires a `String` and a `Set<String>`.  However `map.AddMapEntry("one", "Sony")` is trying to pass two strings.

Comment: Any ideas how t make it so the second isn't a String, because when I try Sony it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is declared to be a `Set<String>` but you're trying to pass in a `String`. To create a `Set<String>` from a single `String`, use `Set<T> Collections.singleton(T)` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T))):

```
map.addMapEntry("one", Collections.singleton("Sony"));
```

Note that the singleton set is immutable. If you intend to modify the value later (for instance by adding elements), you can wrap this in a `new HashSet`:

```
map.addMapEntry("one", new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton("Sony")));
```

Comment: Sorry, i have only been doing this for about 2 or 3 months, so i really don't understand this singleton method

Comment: `Collections.singleton()` takes a single object of type `T` (where `T=String` in your case), and returns a `Set<T>` containing that object (so a `Set<String>` in your case). This makes the second argument match the required type (namely, `Set<String>`).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single String "Sony" as a Set. 
Create an instance of Set and pass it as the actual parameter:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("Sony");
mySet.add("Crocket");

map.addMapEntry("one", mySet);
```

Comment: The issue being is that i need to have a double argument, so 2 variables that are entered in by a user, that is why i have this argument (String aKey, Set<String> aCustomer).

But when i create a map and then send it the addMapEntry i can't create any thing that is accepted as a set

Comment: So instead of hard-coded string literals like `"Sony"`, `"Crocket"` and `"one"`, you use the names of the variables that contain your user-entered key and customer info.

Comment: That is what i am trying to do, my method say aCustomer, but when i test it, i need to put in a customer for example "Sony", but it doesn't work. So what type should i be using in my method header, or in the argument when i test it?

Comment: @MikeHill If you want us to help you further you need to edit more code into your question -- it's much too vague right now. We need to see the entire method `addMapEntry` (not just its header) as well as the code that calls that method.

Comment: instance variable 

private Map<String, Set<String>> systemsSold;

Constructor


   public CompanyCatalogue()
   {
      systemsSold = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
   }

my Method

public void addMapEntry(String aUniqueKey, String aCustomer)
   {
      Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
      newSet.add("Joe");
      newSet.add("Mike");
      systemsSold.put(aUniqueKey, aCustomer);
      
   } (added to main question so its easier to read